# Performing Linq operation on multiple possible combination of nullable values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

The Title and the method explains almost every thing. I need to perform search on the bases of multiple options. I don't want to Write all the possible conditions. Any suggestions?

```
public List<Ticket> GetTickets(Status? status,Priority? priority,TicketLevel? ticketLevel,
        DateTime? createdOn,DateTime? modifiedOn,bool? removed)
    {
        if(status!=null && priority !=null && ticketLevel!=null && createdOn==null && modifiedOn==null && removed ==null)
        {
            using (CRMContext context=new CRMContext())
            {
                return context.Tickets.Where(
                    t => t.Status == status && t.Priority == priority && t.TicketLevel == ticketLevel).ToList();
            }
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the solution by Dave Bish, or use the **ternary** operator here.

```
return context.Tickets.Where(t =>
                (status != null ? t.Status == status : true) &&
                (priority != null ? t.Priority == priority : true) &&
                (ticketLevel != null ? t.TicketLevel == ticketLevel : true)).ToList();
```

There are obvious advantages to either. The solution Dave provided has the advantage of readability/maintenance. The downfall is that it is *chaining*, and therefore can **only** be an `and (&&)` condition.

The solution here has the ability that you can change the `&&` operators to `||` as well. The downfall is readability/ease of maintenance.

Personally, whichever you choose is up to you.

Comment: The other advantage of this solution is that you end up with fewer Queryables to compile.

Comment: @Aron That's actually a really good point, made an edit indicating such, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Aron does that mean the advantage is only significant at compile time?  I'd like to see more explanation of your point.

Comment: When a IQueryable is created, it needs to be converted (compiled) to SQL by Entity Framework. From .net 4.5 onwards the EF SQL is cached. In many  EF queries SQL compilation actually take up the majority of the run time.

Comment: @EBrown The query is only compiled *when you iterate it and get its results*.  Since the results of the intermediate queries aren't being evaluated, they are not in fact being compiled into SQL.

Comment: @Servy That's the way I thought it worked.  The query isn't compiled by EF until you materialize it.  I could see this as affecting cache hit percentage, but not compile time.

Comment: @pseudocoder sorry. I guess I wasn't clear. The compilation will in fact take slightly longer given the more complex query. But the number of times we compile (due to cache hits going up) is much less. So yes, you are correct. But it is significant given the permutations of queries possible, which will also give rise to cache evictions at some point.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to compose your query in parts:

```
public List<Ticket> GetTickets(Status? status,Priority? priority,TicketLevel? ticketLevel, DateTime? createdOn,DateTime? modifiedOn,bool? removed)
{
    using (CRMContext context=new CRMContext())
    {
        var query = context.Tickets.Select(t => t);

        if(status != null)
            query = query.Where(t => t.Status == status);

        if(priority != null)
            query = query.Where(t => t.Priority == priority);

        if(ticketLevel != null)
            query = query.Where(t => t.TicketLevel == ticketLevel);

        //.... More conditions...

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this exact pattern for almost all my search queries.  Works like a charm and is MUCH more efficient than the `(@param = null) or (t.field = @param)` pattern in T-SQL

Comment: Let me check.. Will get back soon. Thank you!